# Undefined reference to 'function' yet the header is included

Tags: c, gcc, include, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I am playing around with the ci20 and [flowcloud](http://flow.imgtec.com/developers/). I have downloaded their c library/sdk and have included the header.

The program is simply:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <flow/flowcore.h>

int main (int argc, char*argv[])
{
    printf("hello");
    if(FlowCore_Initialise()) printf("init");
    return (0);
}
```

but on compilation `gcc -Wall test.c -o hello` I get this error:

```
/tmp/cch4kocL.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `FlowCore_Initialise'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not 100% sure what is going on here.

Comment: It's a **linker** error and not a **compilation** error, you don't link with the flowcloud library.

Comment: Show how you compile your code.

Comment: `gcc -Wall test.c -o hello`

Comment: You probably need something as 'gcc -Wall **-lflow\flow.a** test.c -o hello', where **flow.a** is your library (not sure about the flow.a filename, look in the flow directory and/or read the documentation of the flow library.

Comment: Thank you, I linked the .so file

Comment: @MichaelWalz: The library needs to be specified *after* the object needing it.

Comment: @alk, right, I'm not used to Linux, therefore I wrote "something as". But apparently the OP understood what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a linker error. When compiling with gcc, you need to also specifiy the library you want to link to in addition to just using the proper #include 's.

The syntax for compiling with gcc is

```
$ gcc [options] [source files] [object files] [-Ldir] -llibname [-o outfile]
```

As you can see you can link the library by adding `-l<name>` to your command string.